# Moving and reordering div using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, draggable

I have a Parent `div` which contains several child divs.

I want to allow the user to move any child `div` and move it to reorder the `div` inside the parent using dojo.

any one know ready sample to do this.

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`dojo/dnd/Source`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html#source) will do the trick , just create a parent div , with child divs that should contains `dojoDndItem` class ,

finaly instantiate the `Source` on your parent div

```js
require(["dojo/dnd/Source",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Source) {
  var source =new Source("container");
});
```

```css
.dojoDndItem {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding : 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


<div id="container">
  <div class="dojoDndItem movable">Div 1</div>
  <div class="dojoDndItem movable">Div 2</div>
  <div class="dojoDndItem movable">Div 3</div>
  <div class="dojoDndItem movable">Div 4</div>
</div>
```